# python sqlite why value interpreted as a column

Tags: python, sqlite

> OperationalError: no such column:
>   fcf6082d3ada7b0ed771349398b0d91d5b2cd76f
>   fcf6082d3ada7b0ed771349398b0d91d5b2cd76f is item[0] in my code.

I don't know why `item[0]` is interpreted as a column.

This code works well on another database.

Much thanks! Here is my code:

```
database = sql.connect('database.db')
database_cursor=database.cursor()
hashh=database_cursor.execute(f"SELECT DISTINCT hash FROM commits").fetchall()

for item in hashh:
    find=genugate_cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM edits WHERE commit_hash={item[0]}").fetchall()
    print(find)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi it’s because you are iterating through rows so you are actually on a row trying to fetch the 1st column. Instead change your code to

```
database_cursor=database.cursor()
hashh=database_cursor.execute(f"SELECT DISTINCT hash FROM commits").fetchall()

for item in hashh:
    find=genugate_cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM edits WHERE commit_hash={item}").fetchall()
    print(find)
```

Comment: Many thanks! But the item is ('fcf6082d3ada7b0ed771349398b0d91d5b2cd76f',), thus I use item[0] instead. and I tried your code and still get the error: OperationalError: near ")": syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed with the following code, where add '' on {item}. However when I using sqlite still has the problem while change to pandas read sql, it works.

````
database = "./raw_data/genugate_anonymised.db"

connection = sql.connect(database)
cursor = connection.cursor()
# hashh=cursor.execute(f"SELECT DISTINCT hash FROM commits").fetchall()
hashh = pd.read_sql("""SELECT DISTINCT hash FROM commits""", connection)

for item in hashh['hash']:
    item=str(item)
    test = pd.read_sql(f"SELECT commit_hash FROM edits WHERE commit_hash='{item}'", connection)
    print(test)```
````